# Leaflet: get layer in GeoJSON with pixel coordinates instead of lat long coordinates

Tags: leaflet, leaflet-draw

In my Angular 7 project with ngx-leaflet and leaflet 1.4.0 and leaflet-draw 0.4.14 I want to export each drawn rectangle (and circle,...) to GeoJSON.

That works fine using

```
 public onDrawCreated(e: any) {
    const layerType = e.layerType;
    const layer = e.layer;
    const gj = layer.toGeoJSON();
// .... save gj
}
```

Now I also want to have the GeoJSON with pixel coordinates instead of the latlng coordinates as they come from the layer.

So I suppose I need to execute a project on all coordinates using

```
this.map.project(ltlng, this.map.getMaxZoom()).round();
```

However: this.map.project returns a point object not a latlng object. 
I tried to apply this conversion on the _latlngs property of the layer object, but obviously it does not work.

Should I do the conversion on the GeoJSON object?
Any tips on how I can make this conversion work?

Comment: Pixel coordinates depend on the zoom level, GeoJSON must contain EPSG:4326 coordinates as per [RFC 7946 srction 3.1.1](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7946#section-3.1.1), and the whole thing smells like a [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Why do you want to have pixel coordinates in a GeoJSON in the first place?

Comment: As you pan, zoom in/out, resize window a points pixel coordinates will change but the point has the same Lat/Lng coordinates, this would cause problems. As Ivan pointed out the GeoJSON standard requires Lat/Lng values, Leaflet and other apps have problems if the coordinates are not Lat/Lngs.

Comment: @IvanSanchez  GeoJSON uses CRS:84 (long/lat) not EPSG:4326 (lat/long)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you really want geojson with pixel coordinates at max zoom level, see code below. Since I'm not familiar with Angular, syntax is plain Java Script:

```
map.on(L.Draw.Event.CREATED, function (event) {
    var layer = event.layer;
    var geojson = layer.toGeoJSON();
    geojson.geometry.coordinates.forEach( function(point, index, arr)  {
      arr[index] = map.project(point, map.getMaxZoom());
    });
    // save pixel gj
});
```